# Excel - calculate value between first and last row from search with two parameters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]Short question. I have an excel file containing ID's and Timestamps (amongst other, but that's what's important for this excercise).

I would like to subtract the first timestamp of a certain date for a certain ID from the last timestamp for the same day and the same ID. Is there a "relatively" easy formula to do that?

It would be helpful if it is a formula as there will be new files every month with similar information (and the same formatting).

The goal is to sum the hours for each ID and each month, but in order to do that one first has to calculate the time for each day! So the ultimate is to just feed in the list and get a list with the total for each ID

Comment: I would be helpfull to us if you had some sample data with expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Providing your date/times are in order then you can use a couple of `XLOOKUP`'s.

This looks for the ID and Date.
As the timestamps in column B include the time then we use `INT(Time)` to return the date - date/time in Excel is just a number.  Whole numbers for dates, decimal places for time.
The first `XLOOKUP` uses -1 as the Search Mode so it searches last to first, and the second `XLOOKUP` uses the default which is to search from first to last.

```
=XLOOKUP($D2 & $E2,$A$2:$A$18 & INT($B$2:$B$18),$B$2:$B$18,,,-1)-XLOOKUP($D2 & $E2,$A$2:$A$18 & INT($B$2:$B$18),$B$2:$B$18)
```

[image]

Bit more complicated to do it by month.  This seems to work though.
It will return two columns - format the first as `mmm-yy` (or some similar date format) and the second as `[hh]:mm:ss` (square brackets around hours lets it show more than 24 hours).

```
=LET(ID,$F$3, ID_List,$A$3:$A$33, Hours_List,$D$3:$D$33,
          StartDate, INT(XLOOKUP(ID,ID_List,Hours_List)),
          EndDate, INT(XLOOKUP(ID,ID_List,Hours_List,,,-1)),
          AllDates, SEQUENCE(EndDate-StartDate+1,,StartDate),
          AllMonths,DATE(YEAR(StartDate),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate),1),EOMONTH(EndDate,0),"M")+1,,MONTH(StartDate)),1),
          HoursPerDay, BYROW(AllDates,LAMBDA(row, IFERROR(XLOOKUP(row,INT(Hours_List),Hours_List,,,-1)-XLOOKUP(row,INT(Hours_List),Hours_List),0))),
          Total, BYROW(AllMonths,LAMBDA(row,SUMPRODUCT((AllDates>=row)*(AllDates<=EOMONTH(row,0))*HoursPerDay))),
          HSTACK(AllMonths,Total))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great! I did get some more info, as well. The goal is to sum the hours for each ID and each month, but in order to do that one first has to calculate the time for each day! :P So the ultimate is to just feed in the list and get a list with the total for each ID. :) Do you feel like putting in more info to that? Don't know the easiest way to share the file though. :/

Comment: At least I can let you know that the ID's are in column A and the timestamps are in column D. :)

Comment: A good step ahead. I missed to clarify that there is only one month in each file, but multiple user ID's. So the ultimate return would be one row per user ID returning the total time for the month. (summing up each day and then summing the entire month).

I had to change the commas for semicolon and since each month will have a different amount of rows I had to change it to take the entire columns but I just get the response #NAME?

Comment: Does your version of Excel have `LET`, `LAMBDA`, `BYROW` and `HSTACK` functions?  `HSTACK` is the newest, so may not have that.

Comment: I have just checked. I have "LET" but none of the others provide a match. :/ Sorry! And I don't have the mandate to upgrade in my current organization.

Comment: The Excel-version we use at work is 2202.

Comment: Too bad that the solution didn't work for me because it was such an elegant one. I still hope to get help with a working one. It would be amazing!

Comment: So, I have a bit of an update. The formula that Darren provided was very elegant but unfortunately it produces the wrong results. In my example file the result for ID 2 should be 19,5 hours but with the formula it returns 223:11:00. So a "slight" discrepancy. Guess it's back to the drawing board.